# Sorting grouped multi-dimensional array by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
$data = array(
    'apple' => array(
        0 => array('sort'=>4, 'name'=>'apple_4'),
        1 => array('sort'=>10, 'name'=>'apple_10'),
        2 => array('sort'=>5, 'name'=>'apple_5'),
        3 => array('sort'=>1, 'name'=>'apple_1')
        ),

    'orange' => array(
        0 => array('sort'=>4, 'name'=>'orange_4'),
        1 => array('sort'=>10, 'name'=>'orange_10')
        )
    );
```

Need assistance sorting multi-dimensional array. For the array above, I would like to sort the contents of each group in descending order by the 'sort' value. The group's keys should remain in tact (apple, orange) but content's keys are not important.

Data should be ordered:

- apple

  - apple_10
  - apple_5
  - apple_4
  - apple_1
- orange

  - orange_10
  - orange_4

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the array:

```
foreach($data as &$value) {
    usort($value,function($a,$b) {
        return $b['sort'] - $a['sort'];
    });
}
```

Comment: @LouisW if the field you're sorting by isn't a string, you should use the updated code

Comment: ^^ Will remove the other comments, since everything is cleared. (An alternative to the foreach loop to add this here would be to use `array_walk()`, e.g. `array_walk($data, function(&$value){/* usort() here */}`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(                                                                  
    'apple' => array(                                                           
        0 => array('sort'=>4, 'name'=>'apple_4'),                               
        1 => array('sort'=>10, 'name'=>'apple_10'),                             
        2 => array('sort'=>5, 'name'=>'apple_5'),                               
        3 => array('sort'=>1, 'name'=>'apple_1')                                
    ),                                                                          

    'orange' => array(                                                          
        0 => array('sort'=>4, 'name'=>'orange_4'),                              
        1 => array('sort'=>10, 'name'=>'orange_10')                             
    )                                                                           
);                                                                              

foreach($data as &$value) {                                                        
    usort($value, function($a, $b) {                                            
        return $a['sort'] < $b['sort'];                                         
    });                                                                                                                                       
}
```